# clock accuracy on iphone

Tags: iphone, time

In dealing with Android devices, I've observed plenty of inaccurate - and sometimes downright 
wrong - system times.

I do not have access to many iPhones, but those I have seen have accurate times.

Is the time GMT on iPhones always accurate?  (E.g. speculate you could use network time or build-in ntp or use the time in GPS fixes to adjust drift; all this could occur in the platform so that applications are insulated from trying to determine the time themselves)

If the iPhone time functions do not represent a reasonable real-world time, how would you determine the real-world time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many phones are able to get the local time from the network provider - although I've seen that be a few seconds off here and there.

If you really need to be accurate - you can get your time from an [NTP server](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Main/WebHome) and correct for local time using the phone's locale.